# Javascript in Delphi: [Something] is not a function

Tags: javascript, delphi, function

I am attempting to create a form in delphi with a TWebBrowser making use of javascript. I have a save and load class that allows users to save out certain properties on the form and then load them back in later. However, when loading (Which creates a new form, initializes it and the javascript it uses) the program tells me that the javascript functions I am trying to use, which at any other time work fine, "is null or undefined, not a function object".

So far as I can tell, the javascript only finishes loading on my final end; statement in delphi, so the functions (so far as my program is concerned) do not exist at that moment in time.

My question is this: how can I get my javascript application to tell my Delphi form when it has finished initializing so it knows when to access the desired function?

Comment: Intraweb is for writing *servers*.  It sounds like Xaephyr is writing a client.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the OnDocumentComplete event of the TWebBrowser control.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/twebbrowser/twebbrowser_events.htm#OnDocumentComplete

Comment: That is one of the great websites